# Error when i called the widget inside view class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

[Please look this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4k4M.png).

I try to call the widget form and when I call it inside the view class, it shows an error and I don't know what's wrong with the code.

I'm already importing the class and I can't figure out why would it show an error when I call `_AllFieldsForm` widget inside another widget.

Here's the _AllFieldsForm()

```
class _AllFieldsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const _AllFieldsForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AllFieldsForm createState() => AllFieldsForm();

}

class AllFieldsForm extends State<_AllFieldsForm> {
  //const AllFieldsForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AllFieldsFormBloc(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final formBloc = BlocProvider.of<AllFieldsFormBloc>(context);

          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Scaffold(
              body: FormBlocListener<AllFieldsFormBloc, String, String>(
                onSubmitting: (context, state) {
                  LoadingDialog.show(context);
                },
                onSuccess: (context, state) {
                  LoadingDialog.hide(context);

                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SuccessScreen()));
                },
                onFailure: (context, state) {
                  LoadingDialog.hide(context);

                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text(state.failureResponse!)));
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                          textFieldBloc: formBloc.text1,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'TextFieldBlocBuilder',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.text_fields),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DropdownFieldBlocBuilder<String>(
                          selectFieldBloc: formBloc.select1,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'DropdownFieldBlocBuilder222',
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied),
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (context, value) => FieldItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Are you using this `_AllFieldsForm()` in another dart file?

Comment: yes i use it, but it's already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create private class that why problem is occur.

Create a Class like this :

```
class AllFieldsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllFieldsForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AllFieldsForm createState() => AllFieldsForm();

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have used _ while creating class that refers to a private class so you can not use a private class as publically any other files so use like this :

```
class AllFieldsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllFieldsForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllFieldsForm createState() => _AllFieldsForm();

}

class _AllFieldsForm extends State<AllFieldsForm> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold();
}
}
```